# How is method call passed from `Routes` to `RoutesCollection`?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to understand how Laravel gets all fresh application routes [at this line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2bd0ef74d6962daea31045cb6f15aecb1fe2d19e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php#L79):

```
$this->getFreshApplication()['router']->getRoutes()
```

When I dump `$this->getFreshApplication()['router']` then I find an instance of [Illuminate/Routing/Route](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html):

[image]

This instance (and its traits) have no method `getRoutes`. This is a method from [Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html).

Why does the method call `getRoutes()` on the `Route` instance endup on `RouteCollection`? I also checked the magic method `__get()` from `Route` but it is not evoked when calling `getRoutes()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct type you get for `$this->getFreshApplication()['router']` is [Illuminate\Routing\Router](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html) instead of a [Illuminate/Routing/Route](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) instance.

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot. I thought its an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Router`. If its not a single instance, then what else is it?

Comment: In your question you linked the docs for the Route class. It is different from the Router class (notice the final `r`). The router manages the route mapping and therefore has a route collection attribute as well as a `getRoutes` method. Actually the instance returned is a Router, not a Route object

Comment: I think you just opened the wrong documentation page (Route instead of Router) and didn't find the get routes method there, because it is in the Router docs page that I linked